# add midnight 00:00:00 timestamp if timestamp for date does not exists?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a requirement where the date returned may or may not have timestamp. so if a date is returned like `2021-03-16` I would like to append `00:00:00` to the date referring to format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`.

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: of what dtype is your input?

Comment: data type is string

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
s='2021-03-16'
s1='2021-03-16 23-12-34'
if len(s) <=10:
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
else:
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output:
with `s`

```
2021-03-16 00:00:00
```

with `s1`

```
2021-03-16 23:12:34
```

Simple if clause would do if only datetime is there check for the `length`

> datetime.strptime() class method creates a datetime object from a
> string representing a date and time and a corresponding format string.
> strftime(format) method, to create a string representing the time
> under the control of an explicit format string.